# 1 to Many Relationship Foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I am currently developing an ER diagram for an online store.

Two of my tables are DVD and inventory
I have interpreted this to be a 1 to many relationship i.e a DVD is contained in 1 and only 1 inventory, an inventory can contain 1 to many DVDs

each single copy of a particular DVD is uniquely identified by a serial number

This has led to some confusion for me as I was told that the foreign key should go on the many side in a 1:M relationship

[image]

I would of thought it would make more sense to have bitmap as a foreign key in the inventory table

could someone please explain a method of doing this

Comment: if it helps, foreign keys define a parent/child relationship. your parent (dvd table) can be in multiple child (foreign key) inventories. so your inventory contains the FK field, which points at the parent DVD table. in other words, the many table contains the foreign key.

Comment: `"to have bitmap as a foreign key in the inventory table"` - What?  Why?  The inventory instance to which the DVD instance belongs is something which describes the DVD.  The foreign key belongs on the DVD table.

Comment: What I don't understand is that if every copy of a dvd is identified by a unique serial number how would this work in the dvd table if for example die hard would have a fk serial number but die hard should only appear once in the dvd table and should have multiple serial numbers associated with each individual copy of it in the inventory table

Comment: You are not being clear about two different entity types: a copy of a dvd vs a group of those that--what--have the same title? are the same edition? title and publisher? publisher plus their part number? Your term "particular dvd" is just not clear. Eg what is "die hard"?? You don't mean a copy of a dvd; what do you mean? Serial numbers are identifiers for copies of DVDs,  not identifiers for such groups (Title, Edition, whatever).

Comment: Your wording is odd. 1. Inventory *is* stock. Should "stock" be "catalogue"? 2. Cardinalities (eg 1-to-many or 1-or-0-to-0-or-many) label lines when the line represents a relationship with its own "junction" table. When a line is just a foreign key, the referencing table represents a relationship in which the referenced entities participate.